# upgrade magento to latest version

Tags: upgrade, magento

I am currently using Magento community edition, version 1.7.0.0, and as recommended by Magento due to a major security loophole fix, I want to upgrade my application to use latest version, 1.7.0.2.

What is the best way to upgrade magento version?

I know there are ways like command-line upgrade and using Magento Connect Manager, but not sure which and how to use.

thanks

Comment: This method works for me.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163847/magento-upgrade-takes-too-long-and-never-completes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to go to the **Magento Connect Manager** and press the **Check for Upgrades** Button.

Then you can see updates for all versions.

If you want to Update all packages then take **Mage_All_Latest**

I think when you are in the same Major release the update should work without any problems.

If you get some trouble with dependencies. You can do an upgrade with your console:

```
./mage upgrade-all --force
```

After using force you should check all your functions.

Comment: thanks for the answer @Stony.. I used Magento Connect Manager and upgraded Mage_All_Latest to 1.7.0.2, which did my job.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps:

1. Download the latest magento version(say 1.9) from http://www.magentocommerce.com/download
2. Backup every thing
3. Now remove all files and folder from your site code(mine say 1.7) and put in a new folder say ‘x’ folder.Put maintenance flag and place all magento files from latest magento download folder.
4. Now from magento 1.7( ‘x’ folder) merge the following custom folders into 1.9

   ```
   app/code/local
   app/code/community
   Media
   Your theme or package (app/design/frontend/default/<your theme> or app/design/frontend/<your package>)
   Folders from Skin (both for adminhtml and frontend).
   Copy app/etc/modules/ to current app/etc/modules/ from ‘x’ folder
   Custom admin theme folder from adminhtml/default/yourtheme.
   copy your custom folders from adminhtml/default/default/ (‘x’ folder) to adminhtml/default/default/ (1.9).
   Custom js files from app/js/. from ‘x’ folder
   ```
5. Now go to app/etc/local.xml of 1.9 and put your database and password details
6. Remove maintenance.flag file and run your site on browser, and you are done